# What are well-founded, off-line ranking algorithms for assymmetric games?

Tags: ranking

Consider the following setting:

$n$ players (attackers) play an asymmetric, adversarial, 2-player game against $m$ other players (defenders). Two players may play each other $0$ to $k$ times, but each player will play at least some amount of games. The attackers' goal in each game is to maximize the score. Are there any well-founded methods to estimate the strength of each attacker (perhaps expressed as the expected score in a game against an average defender) under the simplifying assumptions listed below?

- Outcomes of games are not deterministic, since certain aspects of the games should be considered random.
- Both the attackers and defenders have the same strength of play for all games played. Any variation in their strength of play should be considered a result of noise. (No need to have the strength evolve like in elo-like rating systems.)
- There are no cyclical win patterns, so you can consider strength to be one-dimensional. (There are in practice, but they should be considered artifacts of noise.)
- All numbers involved are extremely small. Total number of games played is well under 1000.

Any ranking methods which can be easily adjusted to fit this setting are of course also welcome.

Comment: *"Both the attackers and defenders have the same strength of play for all games played. (No need to have the strength evolve like in elo-like rating systems.)"* Do you mean with this that the outcome is deterministic? The outcome will always be the same in a rematch? In elo-rating it is not necessarily the strength that evolves, the rating evolves as well as an improved estimate of the strength.

Comment: What are match-ups? Or what does it mean that they don't matter? The games that are being played are not match-ups?

Comment: Are there cyclical win patterns involved like rock-paper-scissors? Or can we consider strength as one-dimensional?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus I attempted to edit the question a bit to make it clearer what I meant. I'll add a bit more in the comment here:

The outcome is not strictly deterministic because there are aspects of the game which should be considered random chance for all intents and purposes. What I mean is that each game should be considered equally important for the rating.

Comment: By match-ups, I meant to allude to cyclical win patterns, I've clarified that in the question now. Essentially, if every attacker played every defender enough times, there would be a a clear ranking such that if one attacker scored more points on average against another defender than another attacker, then they will have scored more points against every defender than that attacker. So your assumption is correct, you can consider strength one-dimensional.

Comment: "The attackers' goal in each game is to maximize the score" is this also the primary goal, or is it just a means to a different goal, which is to win a game? One might use the score as more detailed information than just a single binary win/lose value, but if it is not the primary goal than this might not be a good value anymore. To win/lose is not just about maximizing score but also about doing so with the least risk. A lot of good players in games try to play with only a small difference of advantage in terms of score, but a very solid position, rather than trying to crush the opponent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the formula for an Elo system which describes the win probability as a logistic function of the difference in the strength/Elo score.

The algorithm for the Elo computes this in steps and allows the strength to evolve in between steps.

What you can do is compute the ranking in one single step by fitting a logistic model.

$$p_{\text{attacker wins}} = \frac{1}{1+ \exp(x_\text{defender} - x_\text{attacker})}$$

You can do this for instance using a generalized linear model for which there are many software options to compute the result.

You might, after having performed the fit which gives you m+n-1 values (one will be zero by default because only the differences are important), rescale the values of $x$ to get some desired values. E.g. a particular range, median, or mean. Possibly you can impose such restrictions also directly in the fitting method.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace "attackers" with "students", and "defenders" with "exam questions", your problem can be tackled using a whole range of models from Item Response Theory. This is a pretty conventional IRT problem, so I won't go into details on particular models, but the standard *one parameter logistic* IRT model is equivalent to the logistic model suggested by @SextusEmpricus (with a slightly different parametrisation).